# how to set selected value in html dropdown using php

Tags: php, html

I tried below code but it is not set the selected value :

```
<?php
   $form_field1 .= "<select name='typeofleave'> 
                   <option value='LWP'<?=$typeofleave == 'LWP' ? ' selected='selected'' : '';?> >LWP</option>
                    <option value='SL'<?=$typeofleave == 'SL' ? ' selected='selected'' : '';?> >SL</option>
                    <option value='PL'<?=$typeofleave == 'PL' ? ' selected='selected'' : '';?> >PL</option>
                </select>";
?>
```

Please help to solve it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you very neat method of doing this.

1) Take an array of options

2) Loop over it to get select `<option>`s.

3) Check if current is selected in loop.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?php
$form_field1 .= '<select name="typeofleave">';
$options = array();
$options['LWP'] = 'LWP';
$options['SL'] = 'SL';
$options['PL'] = 'PL';
if (! empty($options)) {
 foreach ($options as $option) {
  $selected = ($typeofleave == $option) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  $form_field1 .= '<option value="'.$option.'" ' . $selected . '>'.$option.'</option>';
 }
}
$form_field1 .= '</select>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code.

```
$form_field1 = '';
$typeofleave = 'SL';

echo $form_field1 .= "<select name='typeofleave'>
                 <option value='LWP'".($typeofleave == 'LWP' ? ' selected' : '' )." >LWP</option>
                 <option value='SL'".($typeofleave == 'SL' ? ' selected' : '' ).">SL</option>
                 <option value='PL'".($typeofleave == 'PL' ? ' selected' : '' ).">PL</option>
            </select>";
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be a single selected keywork - not selected=xxx. And only one option should have it.

```
<?php
$form_field1 .= "<select name='typeofleave'>"
                . "<option value='LWP'" . ($typeofleave == 'LWP' ? ' selected' : '') . ">LWP</option>"
                . "<option value='SL'" . ($typeofleave == 'SL' ? ' selected' : '') . ">SL</option>"
                . "<option value='PL'" . ($typeofleave == 'PL' ? ' selected' : '') . " >PL</option>"
            . "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Actually, `selected="selected"` is valid and should work... and he is checking for it on each, and only setting it on a match.

Comment: Also, if you look at the highlights, there are syntax errors here. Opening PHP tags inside PHP.

Comment: You mean the <?= one - no this is a valid syntax if you allow the short opening tag. Both <? and <?php are valid syntax as long you enable it in your php.ini

Comment: @cyrille - You can't open a php block inside an already opened php block. Short tags or no short tags.

Comment: oh yes, did not saw that one :S I edited the code now to reflect your comment - my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes seems a bit off:

```
' selected='selected''
```

Should be

```
' selected="selected"'
```

Comment: Not taking into account that there are syntax errors, opening PHP tags inside PHP. But you're not wrong either!

Comment: I was about to add that in (and give you the cred for the opening tags ;-) ) when I saw that he accepted an answer.

Comment: Might as well edit it - you never know who'll come looking in the future! ;) @MagnusEriksson